# Momentjs, compare utc dates

Tags: jquery, datetime, momentjs

Okay, I loop through an array of times which comes from my server in the following format:

```
2014-04-14T13:00:00Z
2014-04-14T13:15:00Z
2014-04-14T13:30:00Z
```

Now I want to catch the item which is the next from now.

```
for (var j = 0; j < array.Times.length; j++) {
    if ((moment(array.Times[j])) > moment()) {
         // tried with new Date(), isAfter(), unix(), utc() ... "
         // got my item
    }
};
```

This works, but I couldn´t catch the Timezone.
The Time-format which comes comes from the Server is UTC, right?
What I need is the locale Time...!? Or Iam totally wrong?
In Germany I got +2 Hours timezone offset.

http://jsfiddle.net/fool/fDpR4/

Answer (score 1):

Your date strings are in ISO UTC format, so the dates created from them will have a different time depending on your time zone. So if you create `moment("2014-04-14T13:30:00Z")`, it will have a local time of 15:30 in your case. So your sample code may already be working correctly, but I don't know your requirements.

If you want the strings to be interpreted as local time, the easiest solution would be to drop the "Z" at the end:

```
for (var j = 0; j < myArray.length; j++) {
    var dateString = myArray[j].substr(0, myArray[j].length - 1);
    if (moment(dateString) > moment()) {
        console.log(dateString);
        console.log(moment(dateString).toDate());
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: hm, is a strange problem... I will report if the issue is fixed.